# why is the value of b incrementing on its own after 2nd iteration?

Tags: javascript

i am just playing with arrays in this code the value of b is increasing even though the code doesnt gets into the if block?

```js
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
  // Break it up.
  let ar = [];
  let b = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    ar.push(arr[i]);
    console.log(b, i);
    if ((i + 1) % size == 0) {
      b.push(ar);
    }
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(chunkArrayInGroups(["a", "b", "c", "d"], 2));
```

```
expected:[],0
[],1
[a,b],2
[a,b],3

obtained:[],0
[],1
[a,b,c],2
[a,b,c,d],3
```

Comment: Why do you think the code in the if block doesn't run?

Comment: `if ((i + 1) % size == 0)` this condition is true if the value of `i` is either 1 or 3 (since size is 4), so it gets into the if block.

Answer (score 1):

Because when you use `b.push(ar)`, you push the address not the value of `ar`. So when `ar` change, `b` also change. To get your expected output, you should use `b.push(...ar)`, it will create a clone of `ar`.

Demo:

```js
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
      // Break it up.
     let ar=[];
     let b=[];
       for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
       {
         ar.push(arr[i]);
         console.log(b,i);
         if((i+1)%size==0)
          {
           b.push(...ar);
          }
       }
      return arr;
    }

    chunkArrayInGroups(["a", "b", "c", "d"], 2);
```